# strcpy_s ''buffer is too small" && 0

Tags: c

Estoy intentando copiar una cadena a una variable mediante strcpy_s en lenguaje C y al momento en el que el programa deberia de copiar la cadena, este explota y me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> Expression: (L"Buffer is too small" && 0)

el codigo es largo asi que les dejo el trozo en el cual el programa explota:

```
char entrada[50], direccion[50];
printf("DIRECCION: "); gets_s(entrada); valido = validarEntrada(entrada);
if (valido)
{
 strcpy_s(entrada, direccion);
.
.
.
}
```

valido es una variable de tipo entero, y la funcion validar Entrada es la siguiente:

```
int validarEntrada(char cadena[])
{
    if (strcmp(cadena, "") == 0) 
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Que contiene entrada cuando llama a strcpy_s?  Y creo que tiene la llamada al reves, de acuerdo a https://es.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy el premer parametro es la destinacion, no el fuente.

Comment: El código que has mostrado funciona correctamente, siempre y cuando se cambie el orden de los argumentos, primero va `direccion` y luego `entrada`.

Answer (score 0):

Estas comparando cadena con nada?

```
     strcmp(cadena, "")
```

Si quieres saber si cadena no tiene datos utiliza mejor:

```
      strlen(cadena)==0
```

strlen devuelve la longitud de cadena. Retorna cuantos caracteres hay en cadena antes de encontrar {0}. Nunca lo he hecho. Ahora el strcat es al revés. En tu caso estas copiando  direccion a entrada y como dirección no estabinicializada sabe Dios cuantos bytes va a copiar.

EDICION:

Este es el formato de strcpy_s:

```
 strcpy_s(char *restrict  dest,rsize_t dmax,const char *restrict    src )   


  strcpy_s(<destino>,<longitud>,<origen>);
```

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
  strcpy_s(direccion,strlen(entrada),entrada);
```

Comment: strcmp(cadena, "") lo utilizo para saber si el usuario le ha dado a enter sin introducir algun caracter, lo tengo como medida de seguridad por asi decirlo, el caso que pones de strlen(cadena)==0 no lo habia pensado asi... quiero copiar el valor de entrada a direccion, pero me dice que el buffer es muy pequeño, aun si solo introduzco una letra... strcpy_s funciona de la siguiente forma: strcpy_s(fuente, destino), ese es mi problema